# Firebase: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_delegate' in undefined onClick to delete an item

Tags: reactjs, firebase, onclick

Hello i don't undersand my onClick works but i got this message error in the console.
How i can solve it please ?
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_delegate' in undefined**
Here is my code for the props and the delete function

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { db } from "../../firebase/config";
import { deleteDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

const CardVinyl = ({image_vinyl,vinyl_name,id}) => {

  const deleteVinyl = async (id) => {
    const vinylDoc = doc(db, "vinyls", id);
    await deleteDoc(vinylDoc)
      .then(() => console.log("vinyl deleted !"))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  };

return (
    <div className="max-w-xs overflow-hidden rounded shadow-lg bg-zinc-200">
      <img className="w-full" src={image_vinyl} alt={vinyl_name} />
      <div className="px-6 py-4">
        <div className="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold">{vinyl_name}</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          className="px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-red-500 rounded"
          onClick={() => deleteVinyl(id)}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link
          to={`/vinyl/${id}`}
          className="px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded hover:bg-blue-700"
        >
          <button>infos</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardVinyl;
```

and here where i map the cards with cardVinyl

```
import { collection, query, onSnapshot, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/config";
import CardVinyl from "../components/Cards/CardVinyl";

const Discography = () => {
  const [vinyls, setVinyls] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const vinylsCollectionRef = collection(db, "vinyls");
  const vinylQuery = query(vinylsCollectionRef, orderBy("reference", "asc"));

  function getCards() {
    onSnapshot(vinylQuery, (snapshot) => {
      setVinyls(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            id: doc.id,
            viewing: false,
            ...doc.data(),
          };
        })
      );
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCards();
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <h1>loading firebase data...</h1>;
  }

  return (
      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-around mt-10">
        {vinyls &&
          vinyls.map((vinyl, index) => (
            <CardVinyl key={index} {...vinyl} deleteVinyl={vinyl} />
          ))}
      </div>
  );
};

export default Discography;
```